# Callback function on a url?

Tags: javascript, filter, callback, datatables

In my web app, I want to be able to click on a href link within a datatable that loads a second table on a new page, which in turn filters out rows so that the table only displays rows with the same id as the id of the row I clicked on in the previous table/page.

The code below does not work. I believe this is because before it has had time to save the row data from the first table, a new web page is already being opened and it is too late to save the data as it is no longer there. Is there a way to create a callback so that my javascript function is executed before the href link is opened?
Or maybe I am doing this completely wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Datatable.Column() code: (the user clicks on an image/url link within the table):

```
"data": "ErrorCount",
"render": function (data, type, row) {
         if (type === 'display') {
         return (data === 0)
         ? data = '<span data-search="0"></span>'
         : data = '<a id="errors" href="http://localhost/WTM/LogError/Index" type="hidden" class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:red"></a>';
         }
         return data;
   },
```

Javascript filter function:

```
var clickError = document.getElementById("errors")
var xTable = $('#TABLE_ONE').DataTable();
var yTable = $('#TABLE_TWO').DataTable();

$('clickError').click(function () {
                        
     var rowData = xTable.row(this).data();                        
                        
     yTable.columns(0).search(rowData.TaskSchedulerLogUid).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues here:

1. ID's can't be repeated in a page, use class instead
2. `$('clickError')` is invalid selector
3. The elements in question are dynamically rendered and thus won't all exist when the code is run. Use event delegation
4. The row is not the `<a>`

Fixes:

HTML

`'<a  ̶i̶d̶=̶"̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶s̶"̶  class="errors"...`

JS

```
$('#tableID').on('click', 'a.errors', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0]; 
    var rowData = xTable.row(row).data();
    yTable.columns(0).search(rowData.TaskSchedulerLogUid).draw();

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. However, e.preventDefault() prevents the <a> from opening up the new page with the new table. Also, <a> already has a class, so I've used that one instead: "fa-exclamation-triangle" .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested. I found a different way of doing this.

First I added the search query/row ID to the url of the new page I wanted to open like this:

```
'<a href="http://[url]' + row.[column name] + '"></a>
```

then I extracted the search query/ID from the url, and searched the table on the new page using the newly extracted search query/ID, like this:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
queryString = queryString.substring(4);
if (queryString == null) {
throw "Error: id is null"
} else {
WtmDetails.vars.secondaryTable.columns(0).search(queryString).draw();
}
```